# Beginning with two separate tuples, how to make one non-nested tuple?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Suppose I have two tuples:

```
tuple1 = ("a", "b", "c")
tuple2 = ("y", "z")
```

I'd like to return one tuple:

```
return_tuple == ("a", "b", "c", "y", "z")
```

The challenge for me here is that tuples are immutable, so I cannot simply append tuple2 to tuple1. I am aware that I can convert both to lists and then back to a tuple, but I don't want to do that (unless I have to).

I also tried to do this:

```
return_tuple = ("a", "b", "c", sum(tuple2, ()))
```

This did not work because of a:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate tuple (not "str") to tuple.
```

Is there a clean, pythonic and pretty way of implementing this?

Comment: The correct syntax with [`sum()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) would be: `sum((tuple1, tuple2), ())`. But **don't** use `sum()` for doing such things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just add the tuples together with the `+` operator:

```
>>> tuple1 = ("a", "b", "c")
>>> tuple2 = ("y", "z")
>>> tuple1 + tuple2  # This creates a new tuple object
('a', 'b', 'c', 'y', 'z')
>>> tuple1  # tuple1 is unaffected
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> tuple2  # tuple2 is also unaffected
('y', 'z')
>>>
```

Note that you can do the same with strings and lists:

```
>>> s1 = "a"
>>> s2 = "b"
>>> s1 + s2
'ab'
>>> s1
'a'
>>> s2
'b'
>>> l1 = [1, 2, 3]
>>> l2 = [4, 5, 6]
>>> l1 + l2
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
>>> l1
[1, 2, 3]
>>> l2
[4, 5, 6]
>>>
```

Comment: Does this imply that `["a", "b", "c"] + ["y", "z"]` would not create a new list object?

Comment: It does seem to imply that, but concluding that would be a logical fallacy as well as wrong.

Comment: Thanks.  If that were true then everything I thought I knew about Python would have been destroyed in a lake of fiery tears.

Comment: What a thorough explanation for an exceedingly simple solution! Thank you very much -- I'm a beginner and it shows.